# How to properly identify adverbial modifiers?

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

[image]

I do not fully understand what they mean by structure of the adverbial modifier or type. Does 'type' mean the question it answers i.e. where, when, how? Below I listed the adverbial modifiers which I think qualify as adverbial modifiers, but I am not 100% sure and am confused. Any help to understand these is appreciated. Thank you

```
1. hard - How? 
2. every morning from ten till two - When?
3.
4.
5. well - how? , like a child - how?, be bellowed with laughter - how?
6. on one leg - how? 
7.
8.
```

Comment: What do Exercises 1-13 mean by "structure"? Not to mention the textbook this was taken from. Exercises like this are constructed in the context of some analysis and are looking for specific terminology. In fact, "adverbial modifier" is something of a wastebasket category, since everything one can't understand has been called an adverb by somebody.

Answer (score 1):

An [adverbial modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier#Types_of_modifiers) is an adverb that modifies some other word. Wikipedia notes this distinction between modifiers and non-modifiers:

> For example, in the English sentence *This is a red ball*, the adjective *red* is a modifier, modifying the noun *ball*. Removal of the modifier would leave *This is a ball*, which is grammatically correct and equivalent in structure to the original sentence.
>
> [...] In *His face became red*, the word *red* might be called a complement or argument of became, rather than a modifier or adjunct, since it cannot be omitted from the sentence.

You can read more about adverbials at their own [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial).

This noted difference is quick to check so let's look at the examples you noted:

> 1) He worked his company hard. / He worked his company.

"Hard" is an adverbial modifier that modifies "worked".

> 2) They rehearsed every morning from ten till two. / They rehearsed every morning.

"Every morning from ten till two" is an adverbial modifier that modifies "rehearsed".

> 5) If they played a scene well he cried like a child. / If they played a scene he cried like a child.

"Well" is an adverbial modifier that modifies "played a scene".

> 6) He would skip about the stage on one leg. / He would skip about the stage.

"On one leg" is an adverbial modifier that modifies "skip about the stage".

---

In the future, if you are concerned about homework questions I recommend asking your teacher or professor for help as they are typically the final authority on which answer is correct. And they are, presumably, there to teach you this material.

Comment: That's one way to analyze it. But the source of the quotation should also give a list of types and categories, with tests to apply, so that one can in fact identify them, and the exercise will have been designed to show them. Lacking that key, one can only speculate as to what is required.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I agree. I was trying to give a simple start and then point them toward their professor so they can get a more relevant answer.